# How is the pressure of an incompressible fluid measured?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

I've googled around and can't find quite what I'm looking for.. this may be a VERY basic question, but I'd appreciate if it could be explained in layman's terms..

Traditional fuel injection engines have the ability to pressurize a fuel line to ~50psi.

Gasoline Direct Injection/Diesel engine fuel pumps can pressurize a fuel line to 30,000psi or more.

Power washers can pressurize water to 4,000psi +

but all these fluids are 'assumed to be incompressible'...

The explanation that the measured pressure is the force on external walls of a reservoir under pressure doesn't quite make sense to me, in that in order for a High-Pressure fuel reservoir to be under greater than atmospheric (30,000 psi) pressure, the fluid within must also be pressurized.

I don't understand!

I've read that the 'assumption' of incompressibility is not entirely true, but for a liquid to be compressible to 2000bar, the 'assumption' must be entirely false!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The explanation that the measured pressure is the force on external walls of a reservoir under pressure doesn't quite make sense to me, in that in order for a High-Pressure fuel reservoir to be under greater than atmospheric (30,000 psi) pressure, the fluid within must also be pressurized.

The measured pressure is not a force but it is related to force.

Pressure is the force a fluid exerts on the walls of a container (for instance) expressed *per unit of surface area*:

$\Large{p=\frac{F}{A}}$, with $p$ the pressure, $F$ the force and $A$ the surface area.

In S.I. units, for example $10 \text{ Pa}$ ($10 \text{ Pascal}$) means the pressure exerts $10 \text{ N}$ ($10 \text{ Newton}$) of force $F$ per $m^2$ of surface area $A$.

> [...] in that in order for a High-Pressure fuel reservoir to be under greater than atmospheric (30,000 psi) pressure, the fluid within must also be pressurized.

That is correct.

> I've read that the 'assumption' of incompressibility is not entirely true, but for a liquid to be compressible to 2000bar, the 'assumption' must be entirely false!?

I think you may not understand *incompressibility* completely. Liquids are *quasi*-incompressible because when you apply pressure on them their volume almost doesn't change. Mathematically we can write:

$\frac{\Delta V}{\Delta p} \approx 0$, where $\Delta V$ is the decrease in volume for a given increase in pressure $\Delta p$. So even for high pressures like $2000 \text{ bar}$ the decrease in volume is quite small (but not quite zero either).

As regards your title question, [pressure is measured by means of a manometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_measurement).

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I assumed the (significant) increase in mass for a given volume when compressing gases would also occur when compressing liquids.. but that obviously doesn't make sense.  the quasi-incompressible explanation does - in other words the mass of pressurized liquid in a given volume does increase, just not very much.

Comment: @goofology: one clarification: mass is not affected by pressure at all. What you mean is density: $\rho=\frac{m}{V}$. In gases for instance an increase in $p$ brings about a significant decrease in volume $V$, so $\rho$ then increases. In most liquids this effect is negligible.